# Equalize elements height function not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 blocks and I want all 3 to have same height, if one of the blocks has more content the rest of the blocks should adjust height to the one with more content. Inside of each block there are another 3 blocks that I call the function for. After calling the function all 3 blocks that are inside should be the same height resulting same height parent blocks. The blocks inside parent blocks have padding and margin but I've used `border-box` to include the padding in height.

I made a function but it's not working very well. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, it's very strange.

```
$.fn.equalizeHeights = function() {
  var maxHeight = 0;

  this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    }
  });

  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: maxHeight
    }, 300);
  });
};



function boxesHeight() {
  $('.main-blocks .block .icon').equalizeHeights();
  $('.main-blocks .block .summary').equalizeHeights();
  $('.main-blocks > .block').equalizeHeights();
}



$(window).load(function() {

  boxesHeight();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use array to store the values and just return the highest number from it:

```
$.fn.equalizeHeights = function() {
  var maxHeight = []; // change to array to store the values.

  this.each(function() {
      maxHeight.push($(this).outerHeight());
  });

  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: Math.max.apply(Math, maxHeight) // <----get the highest value
    }, 300);
  });
};
```